# Extend Code First Model with a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Tried to separate my customer management playground solution into modules with following logics:

- A `Customer` might have `Orders`.
- An `Order` has `OrderDetails` which might correspond to `InvoiceDetails` which should be part of an `Invoice`.
- `Order` is part of `CustomerManagement` project and `Invoice` is in separate project which is referenced in `CustomerManagement`.

I have defined two `dbcontexts` one for `CustomerManagement` and other one for invoice management, the later derives from the first one, that should allow me to use the entities defined in `CustomerManagement` when dealing with invoices, f.e. the following silly navigation `Invoice.InvoiceDetails.First().OrderDetail.Order.Customer`.

`CustomerManagement` model defines customer, his phones and other data;
Invoice management model defines invoice, invoice details and inherits orders to add a new navigation property between `OrderDetail` and `InvoiceDetail`, now since EF6 doesn't like the use of the same simple named types in one model I had to call the extending type `FI_OrderDetail`. Here I want to be able to navigate like this `db.OrderDetails.First(od => od.Id == id).InvoiceDetail`. Now, I want to prevent awkward searches like `db.InvoiceDetails.First(invd => invd.OrderDetail.Id == id)`

And here arises the first question, since I don't add any real data I want to use the same table, but EF will seek for a discriminator, but there is no need for it since effectively it is the same entity, what should I do? I can use `Ignore<T>` of `DbModelBuilder`, but then all other entities that use that ignored type for navigation purposes won't find it. Is there some other approach I should use or I miss something in my scenario?

Below are sample models:

```
namespace CustomerManagement
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int       Id              { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Given Name")]
        public string    GivenName       { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string    Surname         { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order>  Orders    { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Phone>        Phones    { get; set; }
    }


    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id", TypeName = "int")]
        public int          Id          { get; set; }
        public string       CustomerId  { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime?    Date        { get; set; }

        public string       Notes       { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Orders")]
        public virtual Customer                     Customer      { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail>     OrderDetails  { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int     Id              { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int     OrderId         { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal Price           { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string  Description     { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public virtual  Order    Order    { get; set; }
    }

    public class CMDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer>    Customers    { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order>       Orders       { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone>       Phones       { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Finance
{
    public class Invoice
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id", TypeName = "int")]
        public int          Id                  { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer ID")]
        public int          CustomerId          { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime     Date                { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public virtual CustomerManagement.Customer Customer        { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail>  InvoiceDetails  { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceDetail
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id", TypeName = "int")]
        public int      Id              { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int      InvoiceId       { get; set; }
        public string   Details         { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price           { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("InvoiceId")]
        public virtual  Invoice        Invoice     { get; set; }
        public virtual  FI_OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
    }

    public class FI_OrderDetail : CustomerManagement.OrderDetail
    {
        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class FIDbContext : CustomerManagement.CMDbContext
    {
        public new DbSet<FI_OrderDetail>    OrderDetails    { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice>               Invoices        { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceDetail>         InvoiceDetails  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a problem to use just one context? And if I'm correct you can use multiple contexts. And as long as you don't derive them from eachother, you won't have this problem.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg If I use separate contexts how would I navigate from an invoice to the relevant customer which won't be defined in financial context?

Comment: Why isn't the customer part of the context if you want to navigate to it? I think you should add these tables to the context.

Comment: The `Customer` entity is part of the context the financial context is derived from. I don't want to add it to both contexts since it means I would have to update each time both of them and the financial context will be effectively a copy of the original context with several additional `DbSet`s

Comment: Then why not use one context? The context is just the database representation. You can add your business logic in another layer.

Comment: Since I want to be able to disconnect the financial portion of the solution without changing the context etc...

Comment: Just make `FI_OrderDetail` a class of its own. No alternative. Maybe an interface can help to keep both classes equal where they should be.

Comment: @GertArnold But it would require adding another table or using discriminator, and I don't want to use them if possible...